# how to send a file in response from express

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse, fs

i am currently using [pdf-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merge) to make a duplicate of a file and then send it via express response

```
PDFMerge([file/appl.pdf], 'pdfappl/policy.pdf').then((mergedPdf) => {
      res.setHeader('correlationid', correlationid);
      res.contentType("application/pdf");
      return res.send(mergedPdf);
})
```

how can i do it using node's fs module.
i got to copy the file using readStream and writeStream, but it is not passing into the response.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('file/appl.pdf').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdfappl/policy.pdf')); //copy works

res.setHeader('correlationid', correlationid);
res.contentType("application/pdf");
return res.send(???); // how to send the copied file here
```

Comment: `pipe` it to `res` instead of another write stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream the file data to the connection with `pipe` as it's being read

```
res.contentType("application/pdf");

var stream = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
    stream.pipe(response);
```

Comment: i tried `  var stream = fs.createReadStream(policyPath);
  stream.pipe(res);

  res.send();`, but it didnot work, can you please create a snippet

Comment: You can check this working project. https://github.com/rajdeepdebnath/all-js-projects/tree/main/node-pdf